# Amazon Elastic Transcoder vs FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video, file-conversion, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm developing a website (php based) and there is a provision to upload videos in different formats. I'm using HTML5 player for the front end presentation. So, as the ideal format that is supported by most of the browsers is mp4, I tried using ffmpeg and it works fine.

**I would like to know which transcoder (Amazon Elastic Transcoder or FFMPEG) would be best for handling conversions parallely when there is a huge traffic.**

There could me approximately thousands of users watching the videos and may be hundreds uploading the videos at the same time. I'm using Amazon EC2 for deployment and the traffic is mostly spiky (not flat).

I'm not sure about the acceptable speed. But, I need the one which can transcode the videos much faster.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer the question. What is 'huge traffic'? How may CPU cores do you have? Is your traffic flat, or spiky? How long of a delay from upload to playable is acceptable? Video, like anything is about trade offs.

Comment: I have added the details. please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching is a function of your CDN, not your encoding capabilities. If your transcode queue is spiky, your best bet is cloud (amazon or Zencoder). Otherwise you are building a transcoding farm for peak, not average,  traffic. With cloud encoders you only pay for what you use. But that is only true to a point. If you are unsure, cloud is most likely the best option. Once you receive your first bill, you can reevaluate what it would have cost to build out that capacity (hardware, power, cooling, etc) and decide if it was the correct way to go.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Will be back if I need any more inputs.